# Implementing Karatsubas Multiplication Algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to implement [Karatsuba's Multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) in Python

Here is my code

```
import math
# Base
B=10
# No. of digits
n=4
# Numbers
x=1234
y=5678

def karatsuba(x,y,d):
    if (x < 10 o r y < 10):
        return x*y

    # Partition
    m=math.floor(d/2)
    n=math.ceil(d/2)

    x1=x//B**n
    x2=x%B**n

    y1=y//B**n
    y2=y%B**n

    a=karatsuba(x1,y1,m)
    b=karatsuba(x1+x2,y1+y2,m) #Line 25
    c=karatsuba(x2,y2,n)

    tot = a*(B**(2*m)) + b*(B**m) + c

res=karatsuba(x,y,n)

print('%d * %d = %d' %(x, y, res))
```

But as you can see in `Line 25`, When we perform `x1+x2` and `y1+y2` (considering `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` are `m` digit numbers) one or both sum might exceed `m` digits. In that case how can I make a recursive call to `karatsuba()` with two numbers having different number of digits. Can anybody give simple solution to this.

Comment: I think Knuth suggested a variant with subtraction that avoids the overflow, but I don't have a copy of TAoCP handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should hopefully be a working implementation I did for an algorithms course:

```
def karatsuba(x, y):
    if x < 10 or y < 10:
        return x * y
    # get longest digits
    n = max(math.log10(x) + 1, math.log10(y) + 1)
    # catch where n is odd
    n -= n % 2
    bn = B ** (n // 2)
    x1, x2 = divmod(x, bn)
    y1, y2 = divmod(y, bn)
    ac = karatsuba(x1, y1)
    bd = karatsuba(x2, y2)
    # caluclate a+b and c + d subtracting already
    # calculated ac and bd leaving ad + bc
    adbc = karatsuba(x1 + x2, y1 + y2) - ac - bd
    # x . y = 10 ^ n ac + 10^n/2 (ad + bc) + bd
    return ((B ** n) * ac) + bn * adbc + bd


res = karatsuba(x, y)

print('%d * %d = %d' % (x, y, res))
```

Comment: Can you explain your code. Why you have used $log_10(x)$

Comment: @atinesh, it gets how many digits are in each x and y.you could cast to str and get the max based on the length but I found using log faster

Comment: Thanks. I could have done it with `strings` but it requires `string` to `int` conversion. I was avoiding it as the code would have become more messier. I was looking for some other alternative thanks for your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass the size of the digits. if you did it this way your algorithm would only work for numbers with equal digits in every recursive call. Instead uppon entering the function calculate the number of digits of both numbers `n = max(len(str(x)), len(str(y)))` then you padd the smaller of the x, y with 0s at the most significant digits end an proceed to split both by n / 2.

Comment: I've seen one function `zfill` to padd 0's to the left. But it works on strings.